# SSH Public Key connection fails after logging out of host server

Tags: ssh, server, putty, ssh-keys

I am having issues connecting to my local server using the PuTTY ssh client.  When I am logged onto the host server directly, I can connect with putty remotely without any issues using my SSH key pass-phrase.  If I log out on the host server, and try to connect remotely, I get the following error:

```
Using username "administrator".
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Server refused our key
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

Everything worked fine yesterday and I was able to remotely connect whether I was logged into the host, or not.  The only thing I have done is restart both the remote computer and the host server.  Any help on the matter is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what your situation actually is. What do you really mean by " When I am logged onto the host server directly"? If that is the Ubuntu system, then how do you want to use `putty` in that situation, since it is a MS-Windows application?

Comment: Did you have an ssh-agent running? Was the Putty ssh key removed (saved in registry)? It is possible that the other server allows the ssh key from the _host_ server but lost the Putty ssh key and that is why you need to chain logins